# How can I zoom without multitouch in Adobe PDF Reader?

Tags: zooming, adobe-reader

How can zoom in Adobe PDF Reader without using multitouch? I can double-tap to zoom but it is just one level of zoom. How can I zoom more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only zoom without multitouch in Reflow Text mode, sadly.  `Menu -> View Mode -> Reflow Text` and then hit the <kbd>T+</kbd> button that pops up when you tap the screen.

Comment: My PDF is image based :(

Answer (score 0):

These are some alternate applications for that purpose

[Beam Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.slgmobile.beamreader&feature=search_result)
[RepliGo Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cerience.reader.app&feature=search_result)